# Why is the "SFDX: Deploy Source to Org" function missing?

Tags: lightning-web-components, deployment, authorization

I started experimenting with LWC and ran into this problem.
What I did in VSC:
- Create Project with manifest;
- Authorize an Org;
- Create Lightning Web Component;
- Create Scratch Org and assigned it by default;
I want to do "SFDX: Deploy Source to Org", but I can't find it.
What could be the problem?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Maybe all the plugins are not initiated yet. Did you wait for few minutes?

Comment: You may need to set the org as default sometimes it is being missed even after Authorization. Btw, enabling `push on save` is super handy.

Comment: @Rahul Yes.  Moreover, I have already created a project twice and a new scratch org.Default Org has also installed, and more than once.  Maybe this is not how I create the project?

Answer (score 3):

This could happen, if the default org is not set properly or more likely, the extension not activated yet.

Ensure that the connector logo appears at the bottom toolbar of VSCode and right-click again to see if SFDX options appear.

[image]

If restarting VCode (which should activate the extension) does not solve the problem, try authorizing the org again.

Comment: At first glance, everything seems OK. Added a screenshot of the VSC.

Comment: When I logged in to my main organization, everything is ok, deploy is possible. But as soon as I set the default organization to the new Scratch Org, the deploy disappears. What other settings do I need to make?

Comment: Once you set the default to new Scratch org, did you get the success message `ended with exit code 0` on your VSCode terminal?

Answer (score 3):

As of today (12.09.2021) my observation is that Deploy option in context menu depends to what kind of org you are connected/authorized to (which one is set as a default one).

If it is a sandbox -> You will have a deploy option available. If it will be a scratch org it will be covered by a SFDX: Push sources to the scratch org. I believe that plugin developers assumed that if someone is connected to the Scratch org only push would be used which theoretically should always be sufficient, but sometimes there are some use cases when it would be great to have Deploy option in context menu.

Be aware that deploy do not track changes like push

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it takes some time for VS to start the plugins. If the problem remains after a long time try to close and open again the app

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on my VS Code. **It was solved by changing the version of the Salesforce CLI Integration from v54 to v52.16.0.**

Answer (score 0):

First run the command, SFDX: Authorize an org and connect to an org and then try the same. You will find the options you are looking for.